# Install Numpy 1.9.2 on Ubuntu from Terminal

Tags: python, numpy, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I have `Python 2.7` version and I am trying to upgrade or fresh install `numpy 1.9.2` version. I am trying the upgrade option.

command:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

message:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

But still it has same old `1.8` version

Any other alternative to upgrade the `numpy` version ?

Comment: Seems like pypi is down now maybe that's what causes the problem. You can follow server status at [https://status.python.org/](https://status.python.org/)

Comment: @Nhor Thank you ..its same since past 24hrs

Comment: So I think that is one of the two problems. It's either because your pip is outdated try calling `pip install pip --upgrade`. Or it is because pypi doesn't provide the newest version on numpy, I can't check that at the moment because it's down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `pip` is not working simply install `numpy` manually. First clone the git repo

```
git clone git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git numpy
```

Then enter its directory and just install the lib

```
cd numpy
sudo python setup.py
```

@edit `numpy` happens to require `cython`. It can be installed either via `pip`

```
pip install cython
```

or downloaded from here http://cython.org/#download and setup manually like above

```
sudo python setup.py
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named Cython.Compiler.Main
   processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
    raise Exception('Cython failed')
Exception: Cython failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 260, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 248, in setup_package
    generate_cython()
  File "setup.py", line 199, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!`

Comment: Ah, i didn't know numpy requires cython. For that you're going to install it either via `pip install cython` or download from here [http://cython.org/release/Cython-0.23.tar.gz](http://cython.org/release/Cython-0.23.tar.gz) and setup manually like above `sudo python setup.py`

Comment: New Error `Running from numpy source directory.
Cythonizing sources
Processing numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied`

Comment: hmm, try to run `sudo pip install numpy` outside numpy directory instead of `sudo python setup.py`

Comment: Done already it says its the up to date version but still shows same old version. I also tried downloading the tar.gz file from main site and then try `sudo python setup.py` that also gave error as above comment.

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 14 the LTE stable 64 bit

Comment: try to use `easy_install` instead, like `sudo easy_install numpy`

Comment: @Nhor  I have the same problem as Sitz. I cloned the git repo, but after running `sudo python setup.py` I get: 
`usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied`     Any ideas?

Comment: try `sudo python setup.py install`